# Join in unidirectional association

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

Association between `School` and `Student` is unidirectional. How can I create query from `Student` with a join to `School` using JPA criteria or Querydsl?

```
class School{
    @OneToMany
    private List<Student> students;
}
class Student{
    private String name
}
```

Comment: Make it bi-directional?

Comment: select from School instead of selecting from Student: `select student.name from School school join school.students student where ...`

Comment: What if there were multiple unidirectional associations with Student eg. Group?

Comment: You would use a different path for your join. If you asked a concrete question, with a concrete mapping and a concrete query, it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly join from Student to School, but do something like this

```
query.from(school, student).where(student.in(school.students))
```

Comment: There is no explanation given to this answer. What do school and student represent here?